# Image is returned as raw image data and not URL string

Tags: jquery, ajax, image

Please could someone advise how I return the image as a URL, e.g. https://test.com/006 rather than the raw image data e.g:

�M[P�b�E��SU6)��:5�1�L���O�!��ѻ���������/���������/����iQ���Z��f��E�22������ϊ&f}�l{�����z=ύ �}ӿ^�OG���� Y�^�Zo�/|�K

```
        var url = 'https://test.com/' + id;

        function foo(cb) {
            $.get(url, function() {
                console.log('request has been made');
            }).done(function(url) {
                // call callback without an error
                cb(null, url);
            }).fail(function() {
                // call callback with an error only
                cb('error');
            });
        }

        foo(function (err, url) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }

            console.log(url);
            return url;
        });
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you already know the image's url, why do you want to return its url after an ajax?

Comment: I want to set up error handling if the URL is not available, I'm loading the image into a modal but all I want to check is if the url has returned correctly. If 404 do something if 200 display the image. Does that make sense? If you have a suggestion without using the avoid I'd be very happy to look into simpler solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your comment, you want to check if an image exists, and act according to it. There are a few ways you could do this, I would suggest a `HEAD` request. What it is basically same as a `GET` request except it doesn't return the body in response. So in your case you do not needlessly load image data.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "image.jpg",
  type: "HEAD",
  error: function(jqxhr){
    if(jqxhr.status == 404)
      //Image doesnt exist
  }
});
```